# Running Anaconda Python within emacs on Windows

Tags: python, microsoft-windows

Oct. 2021 update: I am at my wit's end over this.  Still Windows 10, official GNU emacs 27.2.  Anaconda installed in c:\users\[username]\Anaconda3.  No venv's, I just use the base conda environment.  Please please tell me what exactly to type in my .emacs file, so that "M-x run-python" starts the anaconda python, properly activates so "import numpy" works.  Please!  I've flailed around w/ pyvenv.el, conda.el, I give up.

I have a Windows 10 machine, with the official GNU emacs Windows build, and Anaconda Python 3.7.3.  I can't get Python to properly run within emacs.  Whenever I start Python, I get the message:

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 17:13:21) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32

Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment please see https://conda.io/activation

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

And numpy, scipy, etc won't load.  I have tried several things with the pyvenv and elpy packages, all to no avail.  From a DOS prompt, I type 'activate' to activate the conda env.  I haven't setup any venv's of my own.

Comment: From the warning message in your posting - see this page: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html for detailed windows configuration.

Comment: Try conda.el package https://github.com/necaris/conda.el/blob/master/conda.el It switches between conda environments

Comment: Thanks, but I can't figure out how to get this to work.  By "work", I mean "M-x run-python" starts Anaconda python, with the env activated so numpy works.  I have "(require 'conda)" in my init.el, and with or without "'(conda-anaconda-home "c:/Users/strozzi2/Anaconda3")" it doesn't work.  "M-x conda-env-list" works (so the package is loaded) but lists nothing.  "M-x conda-env-activate" asks what env to activate.  <blank> and "base" both give "No such conda environment."  I am stumped.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that you added the folders paths of your conda install in Windows' %PATH% variable[*], the following should work :

1. `M-x shell`
2. In the shell, run `conda activate base`. This will load the environment and allow you to use the libraries (like numpy).
3. In the same shell, run `python -i` (or `ipython -i`). The -i forces a prompt. Without it, the shell hangs in Emacs, I don't know why (it doesn't in cmd).

---

I personally automated this process by creating a batch file called `my-python.bat`. I placed it in a folder named `my-batch-files` which I have referenced in %PATH% [*]. Here's the bat file :

```
@echo off
conda activate base && python -i
```

That way you can call directly `my-python` from the shell — whether it be on Emacs or on cmd — and have a working ipython shell, with all DLLs loaded.

Plus, if you change `python-shell-interpreter` to `my-python`, you get the default functions from python-mode `run-python` (C-c C-p) and `python-shell-send-buffer` (C-c C-c) working.

**Caveat** : At this time, images' display (with matplotlib.pyplot) still does not work properly. I'm working on it. If someone has ideas...

---

<sub>[*] Windows -> Environment variables -> System Variables -> Path -> Edit.
The paths should look like this (check them beforehand !) : `C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts` and `C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3`.</sub>

<sub>You'll have to relaunch the shell (and Emacs !) for the environment variables to be taken into account.
You can check the variable value by typing `echo %PATH%` in your shell.</sub>

Comment: Note: this worked for my replacing `conda activate base` with just `activate base`.

Answer (score -1):

This solved my issue of numpy failing to load on import when using Anaconda3/python on Windows 10 from my Emacs session:

https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10884#issuecomment-499805821

Comment: Welcome to emacs.SE! Please avoid providing link-only answers.  Try to summarize how the issue is solved, this is will make it potentially much more usefull in the future.